# Why does this double integral have the value zero?

Tags: integration, symmetry, even-and-odd-functions

Why does the following double integral have the value zero (no calculation needed)
$$\iint_Dx^8y^7\,dxdy=0$$ where $D={x^2+y^2 \le 2, x \ge0}$.
Does this have anything to do with symmetry, odd and even functions? Can anyone help me with how to think and understand integrals more, especially how to use symmetry to facilitate integral calculations.

Any useful links or videos would be appreciated as well-

Comment: Hint: Think about the integral $ \int_{-1}^{1} {x dx}$. Then think about $ \int_{-1}^{1} {x^7 dx}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the map $y \mapsto y^7$ is odd and the domain $D$ symmetric with regards to the $y$-axis.

In general for an odd map, $\int_{-a}^a f(x) \ dx=0$ for $a \gt 0$.

Comment: Should it not be symmetric wrt the y-axis? I'm really new to this whole symmetry thing.

Answer (score 0):

Because for every point (x,y) in your D, there exists another point (x,-y) for which your integral would yield the exact negative value. So everything gets canceled out.